# How to rate limit scan to AWS DynamoDB for AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli, dynamodb-queries

I have created the following query to query my table :

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name TableName --scan-filter '{
"attributeName" : {
    "AttributeValueList" : [ {"S" : "StringToQuery"}],
    "ComparisonOperator" : "CONTAINS"
}
}'
```

This is causing a spike in read capacity for that table, which will probably lead to throttling of customer requests. I couldn't find any command line option to limit the rate in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html, but I did find a java script with rate limit : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/rate-limited-scans-in-amazon-dynamodb/

Is there any way to do it from AWS CLI?

Comment: did you try `--page-size` or  `--max-items ` here you can check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/scan.html https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html

Comment: @adiii --max-items will affect the number of items which are returned, and that doesn't work with my usecase. --page-size seems like it'll increase the number of separate requests, which may slow down the read speed a bit, but might not slow it down considerably, or very systematically. I need a much more controlled method as it is a customer facing table running in production.

Comment: I'm also open to indirect and hacky solutions like creating a copy of the table and querying it

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call a second copy "hacky" -- that's an integral part of some architectures and is called a 'read replica'. You could use global tables or DynamoDB Streams to achieve this. Alternatively, if you know the schedule of your scans then perhaps you could temporarily increase the table's provisioned RCU as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went ahead with creating a new index over a value which i knew was almost always "Y", like isActive, and added a filter on top of the query. Since it was a new index, it didn't affect existing index capacity.

Answer by cementblocks would reduce the RCU consumed too, but I needed a guarantee that customers would not be impacted.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable pagination and manually make the paginated calls with a bash loop. This way you can delay a certain amount based on the time the previous call took and the consumed read capacity.